# Understanding anomalous memory usage by python 3.7

Tags: python

I am on OSX 10.13.6 on a macbook pro and running Python 3.7.6 from home brew. When I run `python` from the command line, it takes minutes to start.  Once it is finally up, I look at the task manager and it is using ~11GB of compressed memory.  I haven't run any programs or loaded any libraries, I'm just starting the python interpretor.

When  I run python 3.7 on my CentOS 7 machine it is using 8MB.

What in the world is going on? Why is `python` using so much memory on my mac?  It hasn't always been this way and if memory serves me correctly, I think I recently (within last 6months), had to reinstall python from homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I save my `python` history using `~/.pystartup`. I have

```
historyPath = "/Users/user/.pyhistory"
def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
    import readline
    readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    print("Reading python history ... {}".format)
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history)
del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath
```

At some point I must have accidently pasted a large file in the `python` interpretor. My `~/.pyhistory` file was 1.6GB in size with 146322287 lines.  Deleting this, solved my problem and `python` is back to using MB on my mac.